# Using System/User Variables as Parameters in an OLE DB Source Query

Tags: ssis

I have got a SQL command like the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM temp1 a
inner join (SELECT ID from temp2 where ID = ?) b on a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.ID = ?
```

I know the query has incorrect logic. But my question is How will I set Variables as parameters here in the place of "?". If I exclude the joined part, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the OLE DB Source.  On the Connections Manager tab, click the Parameters... button.  The Parameters dialog will display the parameters in the sequence they appear in the SQL statement.  The sequence is determined by reading the SQL statement from left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

To make an assignment to a parameter, select the variable from the Variables column.

Comment: Thanks...I already got the solution. I tried for Expression Builder since I have to map parameter in Sub Querys.